# Javascript: Reference Array Element using Regex Backreference

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, backreference

Basically, I'm trying to replace parts of a string using elements from an associative array. However, I need to grab elements based on backreferences generated from capturing groups in a replace() expression.

Using the first capturing group, I created this code, which doesn't work:

```
content = content.replace(/%(\w+)%/g,this.vars["$1"]);
```

(The regex works fine... I just can't get it to grab the array element.)

How would I go about implementing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can [take a function as the second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```
var that = this,
    re = /%(\w+)%/g;

content = content.replace(re, function (str, p1)
{
    return that.vars[p1];
});
```

Comment: Because you didn't know that `replace` can take a function? Because it's non-trivial? You'll have to ask a new question (probably on a diffent SE site) to get an answer to that one ;-)

Comment: Hehe.. I know replace can take a function; for some reason it just didn't cross my mind.

I'm just waiting until the time counts down so I can accept your answer.